# Cannot get custom post

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query

I want get all the post type `st_tours` associated to the taxonomy `st_tour_type`, when I browse the tour categories in the dashboard I have this link:

```
taxonomy=st_tour_type&post_type=st_tours
```

so I wrote this query:

```
   $args = array(
        'post_type'     => 'st_tours',
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'tax_query'     => array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'st_tour_type'
        ),
        'order'         => 'DESC'
    );

    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    var_dump($wpdb->found_posts);
    var_dump($wpdb->last_query);
```

but this return me just one post, and the query executed is actually incorrect 'cause I have:

```
 SELECT post_id, meta_key, meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id IN (6565) ORDER BY meta_id ASC
```

what I did wrong?

**UPDATE**

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'st_tours',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'tax_query'     => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'st_tour_type'
        )
    ),
    'order'         => 'DESC'
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);

if ($query->have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php the_title(); ?>

    <?php echo 'test' ?>

<?php endif;
```

nothing is printed out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have a missing array in tax_query

instead of

```
'tax_query'     => array(
    'taxonomy'  => 'st_tour_type'
),
```

should be

```
'tax_query'     => array(
    array (
        'taxonomy'  => 'st_tour_type',
        'operator' => 'EXISTS'
    )
),
```

When using tax query without terms/fields we must include the "operator" property.

You can check [WP_Query taxonomy](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters) for more information on working with taxonomies.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I tried your solution but it return `NULL` on `$wpdb->post_count`

Comment: Why are you checking $wpdb? the object will be in $query, you created a new instance of WP_Query and assigned it to $query

Comment: I also tried to add an `echo 'test';` inside `($query->have_posts())` but nothing is displayed

Comment: Could you update the question code to show all the new changes that you tried?

Comment: yes, I have updated, thank you

Comment: Updated my answer. When using tax query without terms/fields we must include the "operator" property

Comment: Unfortunately still the same, no content is displayed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119314/discussion-between-buttered-toast-and-sfarzoso).

Comment: I'm in chat right now..